# Can I download all of rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an air gapped network that I use for development. Is there any way that I can easily download a snapshot of rubygems.org to import to the gem server running on said network?

I saw the help article on the rubygems site about how to get specific gems with no network:

```
$ gem install rails -i repo --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

I want to try to get everything at once. Any idea how big this would be even without the rdoc and ri?

Comment: There are... several gems altogether.

Comment: Sorry, Dave, I don't understand your comment

Comment: There are a *lot* of gems. If the security folks need to inspect them anyway, just get them when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

I have not ever used it, but googling, this tool claims to be able to do that:

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror

Answer (score 0):

you can build a gem server at your server.

I think this article can help you.

http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/

Comment: I already have the gem server running on the network. Until now, my team has been installing gems on an Internet connected machine from rubygems.org, copying them to approved media, passing inspection by the security folks, and then installing them onto the network. I want to cut down on the piecemeal gems and just bring everything in at once and then maybe refresh them every x months. I know it's not the best solution, but it would save time over bringing them over on an as needed basis.

Comment: Your security folks are going to inspect every version of every gem ever released? Or they actually let you in with whatever you want on a flash drive? Security theater, eh?  I guess it doesn't matter, ignore me.

Comment: @user1535152 I think you should write a script to install gems at local, the name of gem list will get at rubygems.org using nokogiri. the final, you can open source your code !